# Oracle select in loop vs select with in clause

Tags: oracle, performance

Which will perform faster

```
1. 
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Or

```
2.
FOR s IN (SELECT id FROM ids)
LOOP
  SELECT * FROM test where id = s.id;
END LOOP;
```

I think the first query will perform faster since it will be executed once but looking at second query it just need to fetch data related to one id which is going to be only one row at a time, that is confusing to me.

I just need to know conceptually that which one will perform better and which is correct way?

Comment: The 1. query will be way, way faster, especially for many ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom Kyte's mantra is:

- You should do it in a single SQL statement if at all possible.
- If you cannot do it in a single SQL Statement, then do it in PL/SQL.
- If you cannot do it in PL/SQL, try a Java Stored Procedure.
- If you cannot do it in Java, do it in a C external procedure.
- If you cannot do it in a C external routine, you might want to seriously think about why it is you need to do it…

I find it's a very usefull rule of thumb.

Comment: And the [source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o27asktom-084983.html). :)

Comment: If I can get anyone to go read more Tom Kyte then the day is a victory.

Comment: Tom Kyte and Tim Hall are basically all you need to learn oracle stuff